# How to place "open a remote URL" image after link

Tags: css

I have a background image to indicate that, when clicking a URL, the user will leave the site:
`{background-image:url('/static/image/open_new.svg')}`

The `open_new.svg` is 24x24

My links are formatted using `<ol><li>`.

I want to place the background-image after links; and my links have variable lengths.

On hover, this CSS steps on the end of the link:

`ol li.external a {background:no-repeat; background-position: left 100% center; }`

`ol li.external:hover a {background-image:url('/static/image/open_new.svg')}`

This CSS opens a space between the `<li>` and the link, and exposes the background-image on hover in the opened space:

`ol li.external a {background:no-repeat; background-position: left 100% center; padding:30px; }`

`ol li.external:hover a {background-image:url('/static/image/open_new.svg')}`

**What CSS will place the `background-image` several px to the right of a variable length link?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CSS `:after` in combination with the CSS `:hover` to add an image to the element on mouse hover. You can then adapt image size and the left margin easily. See:

https://codepen.io/NikxDa/pen/XzMGNX